# Add makers from MySQL to android

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio, google-maps-markers

I am trying to show marker on a map, i have stored in a db (MySQL) the latitude and longitude so based on this i want to be able to display marker on a map, i had follow a tutorial, and so far i am only able to get the json array in the php file, i really hope someone can help me.

Tutorial: http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-google-map-marker-php-mysql.html

PHP file:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbDetails.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `reportes2` ORDER BY id ASC";
$objQuery = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$arrRows = array();
$arryItem = array();

while($arr = mysqli_fetch_array($objQuery)) {

$arryItem["id"] = $arr["id"];
$arryItem["campo_latitud"] = $arr["campo_latitud"];
$arryItem["campo_longitud"] = $arr["campo_longitud"];
$arryItem["campo_categoria"] = $arr["campo_categoria"];

$arrRows[] = $arryItem;

}

echo json_encode($arrRows);
?>
```

LOGCAT:

```
10-12 15:19:56.739 15572-15572/com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta, PID: 15572
                                                                                    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
                                                                                        at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                                                                                        at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
                                                                                        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
                                                                                        at com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta.Reportes.onCreateView(Reportes.java:108)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

NEW LOGCAT:

```
10-12 15:30:51.709 19909-19909/com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta, PID: 19909
                                                                                    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
                                                                                        at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                                                                                        at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
                                                                                        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
                                                                                        at com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta.Reportes.onCreateView(Reportes.java:108)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: I was following that tutorial but aparently they are using google maps v2 and i am using google maps v3 and i  got some errors on the code on android that i couldn't solve @usmanikram

Comment: Can you post error in your question?

Comment: sure @usmanikram

Comment: Done, updated @usmanikram

Comment: use this at the end of your file: header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arrRows);exit;

Comment: Already added it but got a new logat @usmanikram

Comment: to be sure received json data, you should add log after JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i); line. add Log.d("test", "campo_latitud:"+c.getString("campo_latitud")); maybe you are receiving wrong data